# Función que no devuelve siempre lo esperado

Tags: javascript

Esta función devuelve la palabra más larga.

```js
function l(s){
var r = s.replace(/\W+/ig, " "), i = 0, to = r.split(" "), m = to.length, c = "";
  for(;i<m;i++){
    if(i === +false) c = to[i];
    else if(to[i].length > to[i-1].length) c = to[i];
  }
  return c;
}
console.log(l("hola soy la mas largaaaaa"))
```

Funciona bien , excepto con cadenas como

```
a confusing /:sentence:/[ this is not!!!!!!!~
```

***Por qué?, intentando  ver porqué sucede esto, pero aún no logro encontrale el error***

Comment: ¿A qué se deben los 5 votos negativos en esta pregunta sin que ninguno de los 5 haya dicho el motivo por el cual vota en contra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque en lugar de comparar con la palabra más larga (la que almacenas en la variable `c`), comparas con la palabra anterior en el array. Si lo haces así, efectivamente habrá ocasiones en la que el resultado sea el esperado (básicamente cuando la última palabra sea la más larga), pero en otros no.

Si cambias esta condición: `else if(to[i].length > to[i-1].length) c = to[i];`

por esta otra:     `else if(to[i].length > c.length) c = to[i];` te debería de funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución seria obtener el tamaño de cada palabra y obtener la cadena de mayor tamaño

```js
function masLarga(cadena) {
  var arregloCadenas = cadena.split(" ");
  var indexMax = arregloCadenas[0].length;
  var max = arregloCadenas[0];
  for (var i = 1; i < arregloCadenas.length; i++) {
    if (indexMax < arregloCadenas[i].length) {
      max = arregloCadenas[i];
      indexMax=arregloCadenas[i].length;
    }
  }
  return max;
}
var res=masLarga("la cadena mas larga");
console.log(res);
res=masLarga("a confusing /:sentence:/[ this is not!!!!!!!~")
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Devuelve simbolos que no son a-zZ-A , por ejemplo a confusing /:sentence:/[ this is not!!!!!!!~

Comment: @EduardoSebastian solo deberia retornar "sentence"?